# Cross Apply yields nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I'm quoting MS:

> CROSS APPLY returns only rows from the outer table that produce a
>   result set from the table-valued function.

This would mean that it would not return rows with null values, right?
However, my query is:

```
select ....,cat_custom,....
from ...(various inner joins)...                
cross apply
                (
                    select  
                        case 
                            when i.cat1='01' then 1
                            when i.cat2='04' then 2
                            when i.cat2='07' then 3
                            when i.cat2 in ('08') or i.cat3 in ('014','847') then 4
                            else null 
                        end as cat_custom
                ) as cat_custom_query
```

...and sure enough, I get rows with nulls. Wouldn't that be OUTER apply's job? What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CROSS APPLY returns only rows from the outer table that produce a
>   result set from the table-valued function.

In your example, a row is produced - row, which is returning a `NULL` value.

You can try this:

```
select ....,cat_custom,....
from ...(various inner joins)...                
cross apply
                (
                    select  
                        case 
                            when i.cat1='01' then 1
                            when i.cat2='04' then 2
                            when i.cat2='07' then 3
                            when i.cat2 in ('08') or i.cat3 in ('014','847') then 4
                            else null 
                        end as cat_custom
                    WHERE i.cat1 IN ('01', '04', '07', '08', '014', '847')
                ) as cat_custom_query
```

Also, if this is part of your real query, you can add the result column in the `SELECT` statement. You do not need to use `CROSS APPLY` here, as you are not referring any SQL objects (tables, views, functions ,etc).

Comment: I currently have put a where cat_custom is not null after the query, so I'll just leave it this way, but at least now I know what happens. A detail that counts! Thanks for your answer.